# Switch to systemd causes file system to be mounted read-only

Tags: systemd, filesystems, boot, readonly

I switched from SysVInit to systemd on my VPS and the file system has been mounted read-only ever since. Remounting the file system with `mount -o remount,rw /` works, but the file system is mounted read-only again on reboot.

To install systemd, I ran:

```
apt install systemd
apt install systemd-sysv
```

To date, I have tried:

- Reinstalling systemd and systemd-sysv
- Reinstalling `init` after seeing this message when running `apt install systemd-sysv`:

```
dpkg: sysvinit-core: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 init depends on systemd-sysv | sysvinit-core; however:
  Package systemd-sysv is not installed.
  Package sysvinit-core is to be removed.
```

- Uninstalling old packages that were required by SysVInit (`apt autoremove`)

I've looked around but I can't seem to find a solution. I read that Linux systems occasionally do this to protect your data when they encounter errors, so I've included the output from `dmesg`. Other users seem to experience similar issues when there are problems with storage, but I haven't seen any of the same messages they saw when running `fsck`.

Output from `dmesg`: https://pastebin.com/zrRzMqLd

Output from `fsck`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm a relatively experienced GNU/Linux user but I know very little about what happens when a Linux system boots (or why it goes wrong).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a (more experienced) friend, I came to the conclusion that the issue was caused by a missing `/etc/fstab` file. It may have been deleted by one of my `apt` operations. This fixed the problem:

1. Remount the filesystem as read-write with `mount -o remount,rw /`.
2. Run `blkid` as root.
3. For each device listed, copy the corresponding line from `/proc/mounts` to `/etc/fstab` (the line should begin with the same device name/UUID). Do NOT copy the entire `/proc/mounts` file to `/etc/fstab`.

For more on `/etc/fstab`: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/